# Django - null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I keep getting this error after countless trials:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...\tests.py", line 82, in test_profile_creation
       w = self.create_profile()
    File "C:\...\tests.py", line 78, in create_profile
       self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=1)
    ...
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
```

I try to cover these area:

[image]

I am not sure how to proceed testing with other two methods as marked ( `get_screen_name() and get_association_name()`) so guidance would be helpful.

It is my first time in unit testing and still fresh on this so appreciate your guidance, folks!

**EDIT 2**

tests.py

```
  def create_profile(self):
    self.asoc = Association.objects.create(id=2)
    self.admin = Administrator.objects.create(id=1, association=self.asoc)
    self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=2, user=self.admin)
    return Profile.objects.get(user=self.user, administrator=self.admin)

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...\tests.py", line 83, in test_profile_creation
        w = self.create_profile()
    File "C:\...\tests.py", line 79, in create_profile
        self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=2, user=self.admin)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Profile_pkey"
     DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

---

**EDIT 3**

```
 def create_profile(self):
    self.asoc = Association.objects.create()
    self.admin = Administrator.objects.create(association=self.asoc)
    self.user = Profile.objects.create(user=self.admin)
    return Profile.objects.get(user=self.user, administrator=self.admin)


  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\..\tests.py", line 83, in test_profile_creation
        w = self.create_profile()
     File "C:\...\tests.py", line 79, in create_profile
        self.user = Profile.objects.create(user=self.admin)
     django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Profile_user_id_key"
     DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) already exists.
```

---

**EDIT 4**

```
 def create_profile(self):
    self.asoc = Association.objects.create(id=7)
    self.admin = Administrator.objects.create(id=6, association=self.asoc)
    self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=5)
    return Profile.objects.get(user=self.user, administrator=self.admin)


  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\..\tests.py", line 83, in test_profile_creation
        w = self.create_profile()
     File "C:\...\tests.py", line 79, in create_profile
        self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=5)
     ...
     django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
     DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, null).
```

---

**EDIT 5**

```
 def create_profile(self):
    self.asoc = Association.objects.create(id=7)
    self.admin = Administrator.objects.create(id=6, association=self.asoc)
    self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=self.admin)        
    return Profile.objects.get(user=self.user, administrator=self.admin)


  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\..\tests.py", line 83, in test_profile_creation
        w = self.create_profile()
     File "C:\...\tests.py", line 79, in create_profile
        self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=self.admin)
     ...
     TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Administrator'
```

---

**EDIT 6**

```
 def create_profile(self):
    self.asoc = Association.objects.create(id=7)
    self.admin = Administrator.objects.create(id=6, association=self.asoc)
    self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=self.admin.id)        
    return Profile.objects.get(user=self.user, administrator=self.admin)


  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\..\tests.py", line 83, in test_profile_creation
        w = self.create_profile()
     File "C:\...\tests.py", line 79, in create_profile
        self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=self.admin.id)
     ...
     django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
     DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, null).
```

---

tests.py

```
class ProfileTest(TestCase):
    def create_profile(self):
        self.asoc = Association.objects.create(id=2)
        self.admin = Administrator.objects.create(id=1, association=self.asoc)
        self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=1)
        return Profile.objects.get(user=self.user, administrator=self.admin)

    def test_profile_creation(self):
        w = self.create_profile()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(w, Profile))
        self.assertEqual(w.__str__(), w.user.username)
```

---

models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
   ...
   association = models.ForeignKey(Association)


   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Administrator'

   def __str__(self):
      return self.username

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.username



class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(Administrator)

   class Meta:
      db_table = 'Profile'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username

   def get_screen_name(self):
       try:
           if self.user.get_full_name():
               return self.user.get_full_name()
           else:
               return self.user.username
       except:
           return self.user.username


    def get_association_name(self):
       try:
           if self.user.association:
               return self.user.association
           else:
               return self.user.username
       except:
           return self.user.username


 class Association(models.Model):
       asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

       class Meta:
          db_table = 'Association'

       def __str__(self):
          return self.asoc_name

       def __unicode__(self):
          return self.asoc_name
```

Comment: the error is because you mapped an OnetoOneField. and creating multiple rows with the same id i.e 1. try to create with id 2. it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is because you mapped an `OnetoOneField`. and creating multiple rows with the same `id` i.e 1. try to create with `id` 2. it will work, but the best way is not to pass `id` when you are adding it, as `id` is `auto incremented` and you dont need to specify it while creating, but you can specify it if you want to update an existing row. hope it helps

Comment: sorry, i tried changing `id` and without adding `id` with no luck. Take a look at **edit 2** and **edit 3** above, please.

Comment: self.asoc = Association.objects.create(id=something that doesnt exist in database) check the Association table and check the last id

Comment: I have only 2 id's in Association table. I tried some few tweaks and got a new error. Look at **edit 4** above, please =)

Comment: self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=self.admin)

Comment: self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=self.admin.id), sorry about the above

Comment: no worries, still a new error, **edit 6** above, sorry xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144048/discussion-between-exprator-and-niknak).

Answer (score 0):

Profile is linked with Administrator via `OneToOneField` so when creating Profile record you need set the `user`. So in `test.py -> line #78` replace with following:

```
self.user = Profile.objects.create(id=1, user=self.admin)
```

Comment: Its giving me an error that i have edited above. Please have a look.